# dylib load on Mac

Tags: macos, dylib

I'm totally new to Mac but was assigned to fix a `dylib` load problem on Mac, could anyone give any suggestion here?

Our app uses `a.dylib` which depends on `b.dylib`. The app uses `NSAddImage(FilePath, NSADDIMAGE_OPTION_NONE)` to open `a.dylib`.

But `b.dylib` isn’t in the same folder as `a.dylib`. So I guess either some options must be set to `NSAddImage`, or when building `a.dylib`, a relative path should be supplied so when a is loaded at runtime, it knows where to search `b.dylib`.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `otool -L a.dylib`, `otool -L b.dylib`, `otool -l a.dylib | grep LC_RPATH --context`, and `otool -l b.dylib | grep LC_RPATH --context`?

Comment: I found a workaround for this. Used install_name_tool -change to change the reference to fullpath b.dylib to @loader_path/path/d.dylib can solve the problem.